# Html and css form

Tags: html, css

Im new to coding and I just made a html form for  a project to capture data, everything is fine the only problem I have is why the field for the year of entry wouldnt appear on the form 
so the coding is fine but i dont know why it doesnt appear on the form ?

Is the the html form or the CSS ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head>
    <title> Liverpool John Moores University -</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale = 1.0,user-scalable=no, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Add HTML 5 vaildation for older browser -->
    <script src="js/forms/modernizr-custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/forms/polyfiller.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    <script src="js/forms/validation.js" type="text/javascript"></script> </head>
     <body>
    <div id="headerImg"><img alt="header" src="images/"/></div>
    <div id="intro"> Welcome to Liverpool John Moores University</div>
    <div class="para">

        <p>Liverpool John Moores University attends events around the world where you can come and meet staff to discuss the courses we
offer and what it is like to live and study in Liverpool. We also have
offices in Malaysia and South East Asia plus a network of approved
agents who can answer any questions you have about studying here.</p>
        <strong> If you would like more information, please fill in your details below and we will respond as quickly as we can to your
enquiry.</strong>  
    </div>

    <form action="process.php" name="form" id="form" >
        <input type="text" name="name" id="firstName" placeholder="Name" required="required"/>

          <select name="country"   placeholder="Country of Residence"> <option value="">Country of Residence</option> <option
value="Afganistan">Afghanistan</option> <option
value="Albania">Albania</option> <option
value="Algeria">Algeria</option> <option value="American
Samoa">American Samoa</option> <option
value="Andorra">Andorra</option> <option
value="Angola">Angola</option> <option
<option value="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>

</select>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required="required"/>

         <select name="areacode" id="areaCode">   <option value="Phone Area Code">Phone area code</option>   <option value="+1 USA /
included in NANP as code +1-671 (See Zone 1, above)">+671 – formerly
Guam – Now included in NANP as code +1-671 (See Zone 1,
above)</option> <option value="+672 – Australian External Territories
(see also +61 Australia above)">+672 – Australian External Territories
(see also +61 Australia above)</option> <option value="+673 –
Brunei">+673 – Brunei</option> <option value="+674 – Nauru">+674 –
Nauru</option> <option value="+675 – Papua New Guinea">+675 – Papua
New Guinea</option> <option value="+676 – Tonga">+676 – Tonga</option>
<option value="+677 – Solomon Islands">+677 – Solomon Islands</option>
Tajikistan">+992 – Tajikistan</option> <option value="+993 –
Turkmenistan">+993 – Turkmenistan</option> <option value="+994 –
Azerbaijan">+994 – Azerbaijan</option> <option value="+995 – Georgia
">+995 – Georgia </option> <option value="+996 – Kyrgyzstan">+996 –
Kyrgyzstan</option> <option value="+998 – Uzbekistan">+998 –
Uzbekistan</option>   </select>
      <input type="mobile" name="mobile" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required="required"/>


        <select name="timetocall">
             <option value="Best time to call">Best time to call</option>
            <option value="Morning GMT">Morning GMT</option>
            <option value="Afternoon GMT">Afternoon GMT</option>
            <option value="Evening GMT">Evening GMT</option>
           </select>

        <select name="areaofinterest" placeholder="Course of interest">
            <optgroup label="Undregrad">  <option value="Course of Interest">Course of Interest</option>  <option value="Accounting and
Finance">Accounting and Finance</option> <option value="Animal
Behaviour   ">Animal Behaviour   </option> <option value="Applied
Chemical and Pharmaceutical Sciences  ">Applied Chemical and
Pharmaceutical Sciences  </option> <option value="Applied Psychology  
">Applied Psychology   </option> <option value="Applied Sports
Psychology   ">Applied Sports Psychology   </option> <option
value="Architectural Engineering">Architectural Engineering</option>
<option value="Architecture">Architecture</option> <option
value="Astrophysics MPhys">Astrophysics MPhys</option> <option
value="Audio and Music Production">Audio and Music Production</option>
<option value="Biochemistry  ">Biochemistry  </option> <option
value="Biology  ">Biology  </option> <option value="Biomedical Science
">Biomedical Science   </option> <option value="Building Services
Engineering">Building Services Engineering</option> <option
value="Building Services Engineering Project Management   ">Building
Services Engineering Project Management   </option> <option
value="Building Surveying   ">Building Surveying   </option> <option
value="Business and Public Relations   ">Business and Public Relations
</option> <option value="Business Management">Business
Management</option> <option value="Business Studies (4
years)">Business Studies (4 years)</option> <option value="Civil
Engineering  ">Civil Engineering  </option> <option value="Computer
Forensics   ">Computer Forensics   </option> <option value="Computer
Games Technology   ">Computer Games Technology   </option> <option
value="Computer Studies   ">Computer Studies   </option> <option
value="Computer Technology  ">Computer Technology  </option> <option
value="Construction and Property  ">Construction and Property 
</option> <option value="Construction Management   ">Construction
Management   </option> <option value="Criminal Justice">Criminal
Justice</option> <option value="Criminology  ">Criminology  </option>
<option value="Criminology and Psychology  ">Criminology and
Psychology  </option> <option value="Criminology and Sociology 
">Criminology and Sociology  </option> <option value="Cyber Security 
">Cyber Security  </option> <option value="Early Childhood
Studies">Early Childhood Studies</option> <option value="Education
Studies and Early Years">Education Studies and Early Years</option>
<option value="Education Studies and Physical Education">Education
Studies and Physical Education</option> <option value="Education
Studies and Special and Inclusive Needs">Education Studies and Special
and Inclusive Needs</option> <option value="Electrical and Electronic
Engineering">Electrical and Electronic Engineering</option> <option
value="Environmental Health">Environmental Health</option> <option
value="Events Management">Events Management</option> <option
value="Fashion">Fashion</option> <option value="Film Studies   ">Film
Studies   </option> <option value="Fine Art  ">Fine Art  </option>
<option value="Food and Nutrition">Food and Nutrition</option> <option
value="Food Design and Technology Mathematics and Education Studies 
">Food Design and Technology Mathematics and Education Studies 
</option> <option value="Forensic Anthropology  ">Forensic
Anthropology  </option> <option value="Forensic Science  ">Forensic
Science  </option> <option value="Geography  ">Geography  </option>
<option value="Graphic Design and Illustration">Graphic Design and
Illustration</option> <option value="Health and Social Care for
Individuals, Families and Communities  ">Health and Social Care for
Individuals, Families and Communities  </option> <option
value="History of Art   ">History of Art   </option> <option
value="Human Resource Management   ">Human Resource Management  
</option> <option value="International Journalism">International
Journalism</option> <option value="IT and Multimedia Computing   ">IT
and Multimedia Computing   </option> <option value="LLB Law">LLB
Law</option> <option value="LLB Law and Criminal Justice  ">LLB Law
and Criminal Justice  </option> <option value="Management, Transport
and Logistics">Management, Transport and Logistics</option> <option
value="Maritime Business and Management">Maritime Business and
Management</option> <option value="Marine Operations">Marine
Operations</option> <option value="Maritime Studies   ">Maritime
Studies   </option> <option value="Marketing">Marketing</option>
<option value="Mathematics   ">Mathematics   </option> <option
value="Mechanical Engineering">Mechanical Engineering</option> <option
value="Mechanical and Marine Engineering">Mechanical and Marine
Engineering</option> <option value="Media Production   ">Media
Production   </option> <option value="Media, Culture, Communication 
">Media, Culture, Communication  </option> <option value="Nautical
Science  ">Nautical Science  </option> <option value="Outdoor
Education  ">Outdoor Education  </option> <option value="Pharmacy
MPharm ">Pharmacy MPharm </option> <option value="Physics with
Astronomy   ">Physics with Astronomy   </option> <option
value="Primary Education">Primary Education</option> <option
value="Product Design Engineering  ">Product Design Engineering 
</option> <option value="Quantity Surveying   ">Quantity Surveying  
</option> <option value="Real Estate Management ">Real Estate
Management </option> <option value="Real Estate Management and
Business  ">Real Estate Management and Business  </option> <option
value="Science and Football   ">Science and Football   </option>
<option value="Sociology  ">Sociology  </option> <option
value="Software Engineering  -">Software Engineering  -</option>
<option value="Sport and Exercise Science">Sport and Exercise
Science</option> <option value="Sport Coaching  ">Sport Coaching 
</option> <option value="Sport Development with Physical Education  
">Sport Development with Physical Education   </option> <option
value="Tourism and Leisure Management  ">Tourism and Leisure
Management  </option> <option value="Wildlife Conservation  
">Wildlife Conservation   </option> <option value="Zoology">Zoology  
</option>
            </optgroup>

            <optgroup label="Postgrad">
            <option value="MPhil / PhD research degree">MPhil / PhD research degree</option>
        </optgroup>
              <optgroup label="Postgraduate taught and research opportunities- Taught Masters">  <option value="Advanced Computer
Studies ">Advanced Computer Studies</option> <option value="Advanced
Educational Practice ">Advanced Educational Practice</option> <option
value="Applied Facilities Management ">Applied Facilities
Management</option> <option value="Architecture
">Architecture</option> <option value="Art and Design ">Art and
Design</option> <option value="Clinical Exercise Physiology ">Clinical
Exercise Physiology</option> <option value="Commercial Building
Surveying ">Commercial Building Surveying</option> <option
value="Commercial Property Management ">Commercial Property
Management</option> <option value="Computer Network Security
">Computer Network Security</option> <option value="Computer Science
(Subject to validation) ">Computer Science (Subject to
validation)</option> <option value="Computing and Information Systems
">Computing and Information Systems</option> <option
value="Construction Project Management ">Construction Project
Management</option> <option value="Criminal Justice ">Criminal
Justice</option> <option value="Critical Social Science ">Critical
Social Science</option> <option value="Digital Marketing ">Digital
Marketing </option> <option value="Doctorate in Business
Administration ">Doctorate in Business Administration </option>
<option value="Electrical Power and Control Engineering International
Transport, Trade and Logistics ">Electrical Power and Control
Engineering International Transport, Trade and Logistics</option>
<option value="Entrepreneurship ">Entrepreneurship </option> <option
value="European Law ">European Law </option> <option value="Exhibition
Studies ">Exhibition Studies</option> <option value="Fashion
Innovation and Realisation ">Fashion Innovation and
Realisation</option> <option value="Fine Art ">Fine Art</option>
<option value="Global Crime, Justice and Security ">Global Crime,
Justice and Security</option> <option value="Graduate Diploma in Law
(GDL) ">Graduate Diploma in Law (GDL)</option> <option value="Graphic
Design and Illustration ">Graphic Design and Illustration</option>
<option value="Human Resource Management ">Human Resource
Management</option> <option value="International Business, Corporate
and Finance Law ">International Business, Corporate and Finance
Law</option> <option value="International Journalism ">International
Journalism</option> <option value="International News Journalism
">International News Journalism</option> <option value="International
Public Health ">International Public Health</option> <option
value="Legal Practice Course ">Legal Practice Course</option> <option
value="Literature and Cultural History ">Literature and Cultural
History</option> <option value="LLM in Legal Practice ">LLM in Legal
Practice</option> <option value="Manufacturing Engineering
">Manufacturing Engineering</option> <option value="Marine and
Offshore Engineering ">Marine and Offshore Engineering</option>
<option value="Maritime Management ">Maritime Management</option>
<option value="Maritime Operations Management ">Maritime Operations
Management</option> <option value="Mass Communications ">Mass
Communications </option> <option value="MBA Business Management ">MBA
Business Management </option> <option value="Mechanical Engineering
">Mechanical Engineering</option> <option value="Microelectronic
System Design ">Microelectronic System Design </option> <option
value="Online Computing ">Online Computing</option> <option
value="Port Management ">Port Management</option> <option
value="Public Health ">Public Health </option> <option value="Quantity
Surveying & Commercial Management ">Quantity Surveying & Commercial
Management</option> <option value="Smart Technologies for
Infrastructure and Buildings ">Smart Technologies for Infrastructure
and Buildings</option> <option value="Software Engineering (Subject to
validation) ">Software Engineering (Subject to validation) </option>
<option value="Sport and Clinical Biomechanics ">Sport and Clinical
Biomechanics</option> <option value="Sport and Exercise Physiology
">Sport and Exercise Physiology</option> <option value="Sports
Nutrition ">Sports Nutrition </option> <option value="Sports
Psychology ">Sports Psychology </option> <option value="Sustainable
Built Environment ">Sustainable Built Environment </option> <option
value="Telecommunications Engineering ">Telecommunications Engineering
</option> <option value="Urban Design ">Urban Design</option> <option
value="Virology (via Distance Learning) ">Virology (via Distance
Learning)</option> <option value="Water, Energy and the Environment
">Water, Energy and the Environment</option>
            </optgroup>

       **<select name="Yearofentry">
             <option value="Year of Entry">Year of Entry</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
           </select>
>**         
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>

    </form>
    <div id="footer"><img alt="header" src="images/salfordheader.png"/></div> </body> </html>
```

This is the page which is the form

Can anyone help quickly please ? is the the html form or the css ?

Comment: FYI: there are HTML validation tools out there to help you find such issues automatically.  E.g. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/html-validator/

Comment: adding on to @JohnLBevan comment You can also look for online html validator.There are few issues in your code. If you fix them I am sure your issue will be resolved

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing `select` tag (`</select>`) before the start of your year select code.

Find `<select name="Yearofentry">` and add `</select>` on the line above.

Comment: oh my god ! Thank you so much honestly I was so confused because its so long !!!!! You saved hours of me stuck ! Cannot thank you enough !